# Как иметь доступ к массиву из JS в NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

У меня в обыкновенном JS высчитывается массив, но я хочу использовать этот массив в NodeJS для одной библиотеки. Как можно "передать" массив из DOM в серверную часть? Была идея насчет JSON, но пока все тщетно

Обыкновенный код, если подробнее есть у меня объект obj(85 строка), которая содержит всю инфу. И было бы идеально, если я мог иметь доступ к нему в hello.js
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите ваши попытки сделать это? Если на пальцах, то на node поднять REST(POST), на клиенте, ajax-ом передать в REST ваш массив.

Comment: Вам ответ тоже скринами делать? )))

Comment: Ваш предыдущий комментарий уже дал толчок для дальнейшей работы))

Comment: Ну и супер, только вот код лучше выкладывать текстом